# Call paint event on mouse click?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
 private void MainImage_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
 {

     Point[] destinationPoints = {
                new Point(200, 20),   
                new Point(110, 100),  
                new Point(250, 30)};
     Bitmap image = new Bitmap(MainImage.Image);

     e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0);

     e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, destinationPoints);
}


private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

How would I call the paint event on mouse click?
Upon firing the "on click" event, it should draw a image over the MainImage.

Comment: `this.Invalidate()` ?

Comment: I tried but its not working ..

Comment: Use `this.Invalidate();`  or `this.Update();`  or  `this.Refresh(); `

Comment: use `MainImage.Invalidate();`

Answer (score 1):

Use `this.Invalidate();` or `this.Update();` or `this.Refresh();`

And try this:

```
        Graphics.FromImage(MainImage);
        GraphicsUnit units = GraphicsUnit.Point;
        MainImage_Paint(MainImage,new PaintEventArgs ( Graphics.FromImage(MainImage),Rectangle.Round(MainImage.GetBounds(ref units)));
```